# How to speed up animation based on a count down timer?

Tags: react-native

I have a button in my screen that has a movement animation that keeps going right and left to encourage the user to touch that. Also, I want to have a count down timer, so when time decrease button animation speed up. 
I did this :

```
constructor(props) {
      super(props);      
      this.state = {
        timer : 1000,      
        animateBtnOnTime : new Animated.Value(1),
      };
  }

const ButtonAnimation =
      Animated.loop(
        Animated.timing(
          this.state.animateBtnOnTime,
          {
            toValue: 2,
            friction: 1,
            tension: 1,
            duration: this.state.timer
          }
        )
      );

componentDidMount(){
    this._runAnimation();
    this.interval = setInterval(
      () => this.setState((prevState)=> ({ timer: prevState.timer - 100 })),
      1000
    );
  }

 componentDidUpdate(){
    if(this.state.timer === 100){ 
      clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    clearInterval(this.interval);
   }
```

But it won't work, speed won't change and it keeps going in start speed.

could you please help me to achieve this?
thanks.

Comment: The `duration` value is only set during instantiation of the ButtonAnimation. When you want a shorter duration, you have to instantiate a new ButtonAnimation with the new duration and re`start()` it. If would be conveniant if you create a https://snack.expo.io/, so we can answer more thorough